# приложение телеграм бот node.JS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

есть телеграм бот которого я запускаю через консоль, как сделать приложение для бота что бы через консоль не запускать?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js это в большей части и есть консоль. Вы можете скомпилировать приложение в exe файл и запускать приложение. Но работать оно будет с тем же черным окошком.

Если вы хотите управлять функциями бота с помощью интерфейса ( Кнопочек, полей ввода и тд. ) а не командной строки то тут Electron спасет.

Если приложение с интерфейсом а не коснолью то я бы выбрал бы, если честно, C# WPF а не Node.js + Electron